# How to Insert value in varchar as well as in json format in MySQL using Prepare Statement JDBC?

Tags: mysql, json, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
Table Schema: CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `tags` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

where the value of title is `'ECMAScript 2015: A SitePoint Anthology'` and tags value is in json array `'["JavaScript", "ES2015", "JSON"]'`

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Want to write a code which save data in above table format using Prepare Statement JDBC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bjdbc%5D+insert+prepareStatement will give a lot of code examples.

Comment: Most of the links saved data either in Varchar or other format in MySQL or in JSON format. But none of them are like to save data in Varchar as well as in JSON format which is the requirement.

Comment: What's the difference? both varchar and json values must be transferred into the parameter as string literals, no difference. MySQL receives this string and (if column datatype is JSON) converts this literal value to proper inner format. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b57ba6564323103a06635ba0fac0349b

Comment: Thanks, Akina. Issue resolved with insertStatement.setObject(n++, new Gson().toJson(pii.getEmails())); code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insertStatement.setObject(n++, new Gson().toJson(pii.getEmails()));
```